# How to pass through class delared in variable into ClassName with react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I've got the following variables:

```
let backgroundColour = 'bg-green-100';
let textColour = 'text-green-700';
```

And I am trying to pass this class into my ClassName within my render();

```
  <div className="{backgroundColour} p-5 max-w-md w-full rounded mb-5">
            <div className="flex justify-between">
                <div className="flex space-x-3">
                    <div className="{textColour} flex-1 leading-tight text-sm font-medium">
                        {props.success}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The following is adding {backgroundColour} into the html markup instead of returning the value of the var. Any help on how to get this to correct pull through would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  <div className={`${backgroundColour} p-5 max-w-md w-full rounded mb-5`}>
      <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex space-x-3">
              <div className={`${textColour} flex-1 leading-tight text-sm font-medium`}>
                  {props.success}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just managed to resolve it :)

Comment: Great, approve the answer would be helpful for future readers

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the error using the following:

```
<div className={"p-5 max-w-md w-full rounded mb-5 " + backgroundColour}>
</div>
```